# How to add photos for contacts in iPhone 6s?

Tags: photos, contacts, ios, iphone

I want to add photos for every contact in my phone; I tried to for some time but I haven't found any way to set it up.

Can someone suggest me the better ways to do it?

Comment: You need to tell us what OS you're using and if you want to add an individual photo per contact or add the same photo to all your contacts or something else?  There's hundreds of sites that will show you how to add a photo to a contact so the more info you can provide the better our answer can be.

Comment: @fsb IOS 10.3.1 latest update. Yeah I need individual photo per contact, I checked on few sites but those are not helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something from your question, all you need to do is:

1. Launch the Contacts app
2. Select a contact
3. Tap on Edit (at top right)
4. Now the circle at top left will show the *add photo* text
5. Tap on *add photo*
6. A prompt will appear with three options:

   - Take Photo
   - Choose Photo
   - Cancel
7. Select *Take Photo* if you want to take a photo to use, or select *Choose Photo* if you want to pick one from your Photos app.
8. The rest should be self-explanatory

If I've misunderstood your question, let me know.